# SCSS/SASS @each loop Color Palette with HEX and RGB formats

Tags: css, sass, less, postcss

How I can display this **Color Palette with HEX and RGB formats** by using **@each loop**

**Color Palette Variable :**

```
$colors: (
  "transparent": transparent,
  "current": currentColor,
  "white": (
    hex: #FFFFFF,
    rgb: (255, 255, 255)
  ),
  "black": (
    hex: #000000,
    rgb: (0, 0, 0)
  )
) !default;
```

**The result that I expected after compiling to CSS :**

```
.color-transparent {
  color: transparent;
}

.color-current {
  color: currentColor;
}

.color-white {
  --color-opacity: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity));
}

.color-black {
  --color-opacity: 1;
  color: #000000;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it with `@each` and the map.

```
$colors: (
  "transparent": transparent,
  "current": currentColor,
  "white": (
    hex: #FFFFFF,
    rgba: (255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity))
  ),
  "black": (
    hex: #000000,
    rgba: (0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity))
  )
) !default;

// $COLOR = KEY, $VALUE = VALUE, $COLORS = MAP
@each $color, $value in $colors {
    // SINGLE VALUE
    @if $color == "transparent" {
       .color-#{$color} {
           color: #{$value};
       }
    } @else if $color == "current" {
        .color-#{$color} {
            color: $value;
        }
    // SUBMAP - SINCE $VALUE IS ANOTHER MAP HERE.   
    } @else {
        // SET THE COLOR NAME
        .color-#{$color} {
        // SET YOUR COLOR OPACITY    
        --color-opacity: 1;
        // LOOP THROUGH THE TWO COLORS IN THE SUBMAP
        @each $color_name, $value_c in $value {
            @if $color_name == hex {
                color: $value_c;
            } @else {
                color: rbga( $value_c );
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### CSS OUTPUT

```
.color-transparent {
  color: transparent;
}

.color-current {
  color: currentColor;
}

.color-white {
  --color-opacity: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  color: rbga(255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity));
}

.color-black {
  --color-opacity: 1;
  color: #000000;
  color: rbga(0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity));
}
```

#### EDIT FOR RGBA() Function issue

To fix the issue if `rgba()` is throwing the channels error, you can remove the `@else` after the `hex` section and pass the hex value into the `rgba()` function. This will convert the hex to an rgb value.

```
$colors: (
  "transparent": transparent,
  "current": currentColor,
  "white": (
    hex: #FFFFFF,
    rgba: (255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity))
  ),
  "black": (
    hex: #000000,
    rgba: (0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity))
  )
) !default;

// $COLOR = KEY, $VALUE = VALUE, $COLORS = MAP
@each $color, $value in $colors {
    // SINGLE VALUE
    @if $color == "transparent" {
       .color-#{$color} {
           color: #{$value};
       }
    } @else if $color == "current" {
        .color-#{$color} {
            color: $value;
        }
    // SUBMAP - SINCE $VALUE IS ANOTHER MAP HERE.   
    } @else {
        // SET THE COLOR NAME
        .color-#{$color} {
            // SET YOUR COLOR OPACITY    
            --color-opacity: 1;
            // LOOP THROUGH THE TWO COLORS IN THE SUBMAP
            @each $color_name, $value_c in $value {
                // WE ONLY WANT TO USE HEX, BECAUSE RGBA() IS A NATIVE FUNCTION
                @if $color_name == hex {
                color: $value_c;
                color: rgba( $value_c, var(--color-opacity));
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one problem in this changes `color: (rgba($value_c));` they got me an error **$channels must be a space-separated in list**

Comment: That's because SASS has a built in `rgba()` function. Hold on, I'll add another way.

Comment: @houssamdetective1105 updated with a new block of code that only uses the `hex` value.